# How to map aggregated data from Firestore document back to a Kotlin List

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]Would like to reduce the number of reads in my app with Firestore. So I created a document in my collection with the following structure to hold values for 10 "records", that I will get with a single read - since the size of this document is pretty decent, no worries about the 1MB limit size for a single document. I am updating the content of this document with cloud functions.

```
name of collection: helperz
name of document: top10
field name in top10: tresholdCounter - this I need to check if a single map should be added to top10 or not
field name in top10: top10 . . array of maps


helperz/top10/tresholdCounter
helperz/top10/top10/0/author
helperz/top10/top10/0/name
helperz/top10/top10/0/url
helperz/top10/top10/1/author
helperz/top10/top10/1/name
helperz/top10/top10/1/url
helperz/top10/top10/2/author
helperz/top10/top10/2/name
helperz/top10/top10/2/url
helperz/top10/top10/3/author
helperz/top10/top10/3/name
helperz/top10/top10/3/url
helperz/top10/top10/4/author
helperz/top10/top10/4/name
helperz/top10/top10/4/url
..
helperz/top10/top10/10/author
helperz/top10/top10/10/name
helperz/top10/top10/10/url
```

I have a data class . . like this:

```
data class MyClass(
    var name: String? = null,
    var url: String? = null,
    var author: String? = null,
    var counter: Int = 0,
    var free: Boolean? = false,
    var global: Boolean?=true,
    var poses: ArrayList<MyPoze>? = null,
    var docId: string? = null,
    var category: ArrayList<String>? = null,
    @get:PropertyName(CREATED)
    @set:PropertyName(CREATED)
    @ServerTimestamp var created: Timestamp? = null
    )
```

There are some other fields as well, but for the purpose of this problem, that should be ok.

I have a code for retrieving data from Firestore (in my viewModel):

```
private fun getHelperzTop10() = viewModelScope.launch {
    Log.d("MP23", "getHelperzTop10")
    val docRef = db.collection("helperz").document("top10")

    docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("MP23", "Listen failed.", e)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            val docSize = firestoreDocument.getSize(snapshot);
            Log.d("MP23","docSize in Bytes: $docSize, in KB: ${docSize * 0.001}, in MB: ${docSize * 0.000001}"
            )
            val top10 = snapshot.data
            Log.d("MP23", top10!!::class.simpleName.toString() )

            if ("top10" in keys) {
                val top10arr = top10["top10"] as ArrayList<MyClass>
                Log.d("MP23", "we have top10 in top10")
                Log.d("MP23", top10arr!!::class.simpleName.toString())
                Log.d("MP23", top10arr.toString())
            ////  PROBLEM HERE ///                
            // here I need somehow to cast this array of maps as MyClass, but I am getting error:
            // java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.MyClass
            // or
            // java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[] - with some other versions
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("MP23", "Current data: null")
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can suggest how can I cast result to MyClass, that would be great. In normal situation (where I have documents that I query against) nicely as single docs, I can easily do:

```
val singleRec = singleRec.toObject(MyClass::class.java)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo The problem and error message are indicated in the second to last code block. I edited the question to highlight them better.

Comment: @GregoSotošek: can you replace the structure of your document in the first code block with a screenshot of the document in the Firebase console? That's more likely to show exactly what we need to answer how to map it to your Android code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, have added screenshot of document from which I need to map the data into MyClass. HOpe it's clear now what my problem is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I would like to extract data about author, url, .... so that I can create MyClass with this params. .

Comment: Your class is missing `category` and `created` properties, which should raise an error afaik.

Comment: That is not the problem, just missed them when posting a question. Problem is I am unable (don't know how) to parse a data that I receive from Firestore. Currentlly I have strings, which I am unable to parse back to MyClass. There are a couple of strings but also a 2 ArrayLists I should somehow "parse back" to MyClass. I thought this could be done with Gson or JSONObject, but unfortunately am unable so far.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, puf. I just answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `top10` array as a `List<MyClass>`, the simplest solution that I can think of would be to create another class:

```
data class Document(
    var top10: MutableList<MyClass>? = null
)
```

And read the content of the document like this:

```
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        snapshot?.let {
            val document = snapshot.toObject(Document::class.java)
            document?.let {
                val top10 = document.top10
                top10?.let {
                    for (myClass in top10) {
                        val name =  myClass.name
                        Log.d("TAG", "$name")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        it.exception?.message?.let { message ->
            Log.d("TAG", message) //Never ignore potential errors!   
        }
    }
}
```

I will also recommend you read the following resource for a better understanding:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo. This is exactly what I needed.  Keep sharing stuff..

Comment: Good to hear that, Gregor. You're very welcome!